# Java Spring: JUnit Hamcrest: Expecting Collection

Tags: java, spring, junit, hamcrest

i'm running my integration test suite in my Java Spring Web application, however running into the following error.

There is a single item value: {id value} for id, returned in the response.

```
java.lang.AssrtionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path data.id doesn't match.
Expected: a collection containing "BUNDLE_A"
Actual: BUNDLE_A
```

IntegrationTest.java:

```
 @Test
  public void testBundle() throws Exception {
    RestAssured.when()
      .get("v1/bundles/{bundleId}", TEST_BUNDLE_ID)
    .then()
      .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
      .body("data.id", hasItem(TEST_BUNDLE_ID))
      .body("errorCode", nullValue());
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `hasItem` with `equalTo`:

```
 @Test
  public void testBundle() throws Exception {
    RestAssured.when()
      .get("v1/bundles/{bundleId}", TEST_BUNDLE_ID)
    .then()
      .statusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
      .body("data.id", equalTo(TEST_BUNDLE_ID))
      .body("errorCode", nullValue());
  }
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: The method equalTo(String) is undefined for the type IntegrationTest

Comment: Do you imported it? `import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo`

Comment: Thanks, that was it!